# Slow/Not Working Media Library Search

Tags: media-library

I'm working with a site that has 1500+ images in the media library and when I search to add an image to a post, the search is taking too long or not working.

Is there such thing as too many images in a library or does it have to do with something else?

Comment: Define _"slow"_ please. It might have many reasons. Slow browser, weak laptop, slow connection, slow server, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress media library do not scale well especially when searching for images. I know there was some work done in trying to make it better in the latest versions but there are some fundamental problems (flat structure) that are unlikely to be resolved without some refactoring of the whole code.

If this is an essential part of your work flow, then the easiest thing to do will be to get better hardware to make searching faster.